# Echo textarea's value with PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to `echo` the `textarea` value with PHP, so I create a simple form with HTML, and inside it I include `textarea` element with name of `b64_place` and then `input` to submit the values.

I check if `b64_place` is set, and if it is I echo the value of the `textarea`. But my program doesn't even get into the condition block, I try debugging and it is just not doing nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="index.php" method="GET">
            <textarea name="b64_place" form="encode">Enter text here:</textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Encode">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_GET['b64_place'])) {
                $base64e_text = htmlspecialchars($_GET['b64_place']);
                echo $base64e_text;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know php offers a `alert()` function ;)

Comment: @B001ᛦ Ohhh my fault. I meant to echo it out

Comment: `echo` should work fine. If it doesn't, check View Source in the browser. If you see your raw PHP there, then you don't have PHP running.

Comment: Your current code should work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I run the following command `php -S localhost:9000/index.php` to setup a php web server and everything looks fine, also in the firefox console. But I still get no output with `echo`

Comment: `php -S localhost:9000` is all you need. Once you submit the form, do you see `index.php?b64_place=what+you+typed`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol No, I don't see it. weird.

Comment: That's certainly because of the `form` attribute of the `<textarea>`

Comment: Oh, wait a second. Remove `form="encode"` from the `textarea`. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Cid Thanks, I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textarea contains an attribute [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefform) This attribute is used to define the id of the form this input is attached to. So, when you submit the form, the textarea isn't bound with that form and the datas aren't send

You can either add an id to the form :

```
<!-- check this ----------------------v---------v -->
<form action="index.php" method="GET" id="encode">
    <textarea name="b64_place" form="encode">Enter text here:</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Encode">
</form>
```

or simply remove the `form="encode"`

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could assign specific elements to forms, I always thought the `form` attribute was just for the submit button. I can't think of any cases where this would be useful off the top of my head, but it's pretty cool!

Comment: Well, it could be used, in example in a `table` of differents forms, where each column is a form

Answer (score 1):

**Edit based on suggestion from senior SO members,**
*The reason i recommend you to change the method to POST is because of the length limit of the GET method. At some point you may want to encode very large data and it may get trimmed of because of URL length limit. But with POST you don't have to worry about this restriction.*
Steps to solve your issue.

1. If your Form and your PHP code is in the same file changethe action="index.php" to action="" and change the method="GET" to method="POST"
2. In text area use placeholder to tell the user what to input instead of writing it between the  tags.
3. change $_GET to $_POST everywhere in your code.

You can copy the following code into the index.php and it will work fine.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <textarea name="b64_place" placeholder="Enter text here:"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Encode">
            </form>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['b64_place'])) {
                    $base64e_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['b64_place']);
                    echo $base64e_text;
                }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why should OP change the method to `POST` ? You missed the most important part, about the `form=` attribute

Comment: There are valid reasons to use GET. e.g. search results can be searched with other users if a GET is used.

Comment: Yeah sure $_GET can also be used. Perhaps you could tell me if i shouldn't favor POST over GET.  I used POST because GET have length restriction because of the url length limit. :-)

Comment: I don't want POST. I want other users to be allowed to send links with a text in the URL